# How can I write a local XML file?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

I am new to this website and also to AS3 programming.

Currently I am trying to write a local XML using Air.
However everytime I press the button that generates the file, the .exe closes without saving the file.

The app instead works correctly when I test it in Animate (Ctrl+Enter) and the XML file is currently created and updated everytime.

Here's the code I am using:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
outButton.visible = false;
inButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ingfx);

function ingfx(event: MouseEvent): void {
var prefsXML: XML = <gfx> 
<inout>1</inout>
<player>{selector_mc.selected_player}</player>
</gfx> ;
var file: File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("c:\\test\\gfx.xml");
var fileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);

var outputString: String = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n';
outputString += prefsXML.toXMLString();

fileStream.writeUTFBytes(outputString);
fileStream.close();
inButton.visible = false;
outButton.visible = true;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? I would like the app to stay open after the XML writing. Compiler shows no errors.

Thank you!

Comment: try adding a listener for http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#event:complete and calling `fileStream.close();` there

Comment: also according to http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#writeUTFBytes%28%29 `writeUTFBytes()` throws `IOError`, try wrapping your call like `try{ fileStream.writeUTFBytes(outputString); } catch(er:Error){trace(er, er.getStackTrace)}` (or if it not a debug runtime - output the text somewhere in your app)

Comment: @DiegoG I think that your problem is coming from this line : `var file: File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("c:\\test\\gfx.xml");`, if you want to use an absolute path try : `var file: File = new File("c:\\test\\gfx.xml");` ...

Comment: @www0z0k - adding what you wrote gave me this: Error: Error #2029: This URLStream object does not have a stream opened. function Function() {}.

Comment: @akmozo - tried your suggestion with same result. In Animate the writing of file is working, when launching the exe, it closes without updating the xml

Comment: @DiegoG `er.getStackTrace()` instead of `er.getStackTrace` - my typo, sorry

Comment: What do the double backslashes in your file path mean? `"c:\\test\\gfx.xml"`

Comment: Still nothing. App continues to close when clicking on the button.

Comment: @Will Tower - I Always added that extra character when referring to a local absolute path, otherwise it does not find the path

Comment: Hello again guys! I just solved it by myself. It was a security problem. I changed the certificate properties for the AIR file and created a new certificate.
Now everything is running smooth.
Thanks everybody for the support.

Comment: @DiegoG - about the paths – ok, never used that syntax and it isn't what Adobe recommends for cross-platform compatibility – but it sounds like it doesn't matter for your project.